# How to get rss feeds for live soccer gamecast in developing an android app

Tags: android

I am new to android development, and i have a bit of an issue. I want to develop an app in which i can get live gamecasts of soccer games on the app. I am not sure of whether some of the soccer websites like ESPN have provisions for such rss feeds. I am not sure if i can get the gamecasts directly on my app, without it redirecting me to the website itself

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to those RSS feeds you can parse them using the DocumentBuilderFactory

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are willing, you can buy subscriptions for XML API services to get a more structured way of getting data. I have used http://www.xmlsoccer.com for quite some time now. They are pretty affordable and they offer one demo-league for free with no timelimit so you can take all the time you need developing up against their API without having to pay anything.